# Apostrophe getting converted to code while saving

Tags: apex, lightning, javascript

I am getting the value from a text area and sending it to apex for saving.

For example this:-
You're orange.

This value appears properly in console logs and apex debugs.

However when I SOQL, it changes to this-
`You&#39;re orange`. **Edit: the resulting escaping was invisible**

I tried using the escapeSingleQuote string function, it didn't work.

Here is my code;

```
    var action = component.get("c.setEmployerMessage");
    //This is important, as it converts it to text type.
    var employerMsg = component.get("v.employerMessage");
    console.log('employerMsg-->'+component.get("v.employerMessage"));
    console.log('employerMsg Variable-->'+employerMsg);
    action.setParams({strMessage:employerMsg});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
```

Apex

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void setEmployerMessage(String strMessage){
    try{
        System.debug('Message in set-->'+strMessage);
        System.debug('Single quote process-->'+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(strMessage));
        User currentUser = CarynCommonUtilityClass.getLoggedInUserDetails();
        List<Account> lstAccountToUpdate = [Select Id,Enrollment_Message__c,Name
                                            from Account
                                           where Id=:currentUser.Contact.AccountId];
        Account accToUpdate = lstAccountToUpdate[0];
        System.debug('accToUpdate in set-->'+accToUpdate.Name);
        accToUpdate.Enrollment_Message__c = strMessage;
        update accToUpdate;
```

Debug Logs:-

> 09:35:25.0 (393694)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Aura
>   09:35:25.0 (2369747)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p2E000009apFH|PersonalizeMessageController.setEmployerMessage(String)
>   09:35:25.0 (2524639)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[79]|Bytes:3
>   09:35:25.0 (2598850)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[84]|Bytes:152
>   09:35:25.0 (2622730)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[399]|Bytes:408
>   09:35:25.0 (2646436)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[412]|Bytes:408
>   09:35:25.0 (2668874)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[520]|Bytes:48
>   09:35:25.0 (2726819)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[139]|Bytes:6
>   09:35:25.0 (2799394)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:5
>   09:35:25.0 (2808782)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
>   09:35:25.0 (2824778)|METHOD_ENTRY|[15]|01p2E000009apFH|PersonalizeMessageController.PersonalizeMessageController()
>   09:35:25.0 (2834893)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[15]
>   09:35:25.0 (2843754)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[15]
>   09:35:25.0 (2892454)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[52]|Bytes:5
>   09:35:25.0 (2919582)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[58]|Bytes:5
>   09:35:25.0 (2928416)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[66]|Bytes:7
>   09:35:25.0 (2949451)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
>   09:35:25.0 (2965143)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:5
>   09:35:25.0 (2973269)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
>   09:35:25.0 (2981647)|METHOD_EXIT|[15]|PersonalizeMessageController
>   09:35:25.0 (2987799)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:14
>   09:35:25.0 (2994422)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
>   09:35:25.0 (3000237)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[44]|strMessage|String|false|false
>   09:35:25.0 (3052701)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[44]|strMessage|"You're Orange."
>   09:35:25.0 (3080347)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[45]|Bytes:5
>   09:35:25.0 (3086222)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[44]
>   09:35:25.0 (3088951)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[45]
>   09:35:25.0 (3091192)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[45]
>   09:35:25.0 (3093522)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[46]
>   09:35:25.0 (3097048)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[46]|Bytes:17
>   09:35:25.0 (3113707)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[46]|Bytes:31
>   09:35:25.0 (3141542)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[46]|System.debug(ANY)
>   09:35:25.0 (3166657)|USER_DEBUG|[46]|DEBUG|Message in set-->You're Orange.
>   09:35:25.0 (3176813)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[46]|System.debug(ANY)
>   09:35:25.0 (3181888)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[48]
>   09:35:25.0 (3760297)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[48]|Bytes:40
>   09:35:25.0 (3778364)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[48]|Bytes:39
>   09:35:25.0 (3794678)|METHOD_ENTRY|[14]|01p2E000009apE9|CarynCommonUtilityClass.CarynCommonUtilityClass()
>   09:35:25.0 (3803511)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[14]
>   09:35:25.0 (3809320)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[14]
>   09:35:25.0 (3822503)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   09:35:25.0 (3833715)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[48]|Bytes:5
>   09:35:25.0 (3842954)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|true
>   09:35:25.0 (3854989)|METHOD_EXIT|[14]|CarynCommonUtilityClass
>   09:35:25.0 (3875642)|METHOD_ENTRY|[48]|01p2E000009apE9|CarynCommonUtilityClass.getLoggedInUserDetails()
>   09:35:25.0 (3902494)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   09:35:25.0 (3909274)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[22]|Bytes:5
>   09:35:25.0 (3917358)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[21]
>   09:35:25.0 (3921116)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[22]
>   09:35:25.0 (3924060)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[22]
>   09:35:25.0 (3926710)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[23]
>   09:35:25.0 (3931578)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[23]|Bytes:146
>   09:35:25.0 (3962696)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[23]|Bytes:4
>   09:35:25.0 (3979332)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[23]|Bytes:7
>   09:35:25.0 (14978600)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[25]|Bytes:97
>   09:35:25.0 (15037895)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|UserInfo.UserInfo()
>   09:35:25.0 (15054016)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
>   09:35:25.0 (15067840)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[1]|UserInfo
>   09:35:25.0 (15091177)|METHOD_ENTRY|[25]||System.UserInfo.getUserId()
>   09:35:25.0 (38509070)|METHOD_EXIT|[25]||System.UserInfo.getUserId()
>   09:35:25.0 (42655750)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[23]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, ContactId, Contact.AccountId, Contact.Account.Enrollment_Status__c, Contact.Account.Enrollment_Message__c FROM User WHERE Id = :tmpVar1
>   09:35:25.0 (42681708)|LIMIT_USAGE|[23]|SOQL|1|100
>   09:35:25.0 (42706859)|LIMIT_USAGE|[23]|AGGS|0|300
>   09:35:25.0 (55319612)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[23]|Rows:1
>   09:35:25.0 (55341427)|LIMIT_USAGE|[23]|SOQL_ROWS|1|50000
>   09:35:25.0 (55371714)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[23]|Bytes:8
>   09:35:25.0 (55392336)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[23]|Bytes:259
>   09:35:25.0 (55545869)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[23]|Bytes:8
>   09:35:25.0 (55571611)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[23]|usr|List|true|false
>   09:35:25.0 (55624415)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[23]|usr|[{"Id":"0058A000002NQhiQAG","ContactId":"0038A00000Gag87QAB","Contact":{"AccountId":"0018A00000MJsXBQA1","Id":"0038A00000Gag87QAB","Account":{"Enrollment_Status__c":"Quote Accepted","Enrollment_Message__c":"You're Personal  (7 more) ...","Id":"0018A00000MJsXBQA1"}}}]|0x60343f2b
>   09:35:25.0 (55636099)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[27]
>   09:35:25.0 (55707998)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[27]|Bytes:16
>   09:35:25.0 (55721714)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|true
>   09:35:25.0 (56297785)|METHOD_EXIT|[48]|01p2E000009apE9|CarynCommonUtilityClass.getLoggedInUserDetails()
>   09:35:25.0 (56313917)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[48]|currentUser|User|true|false
>   09:35:25.0 (56353249)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[48]|currentUser|{"Id":"0058A000002NQhiQAG","ContactId":"0038A00000Gag87QAB","Contact":{"AccountId":"0018A00000MJsXBQA1","Id":"0038A00000Gag87QAB","Account":{"Enrollment_Status__c":"Quote Accepted","Enrollment_Message__c":"You're Personal  (7 more) ...","Id":"0018A00000MJsXBQA1"}}}|0x1a5ab411
>   09:35:25.0 (56361978)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[49]
>   09:35:25.0 (56368994)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[49]|Bytes:71
>   09:35:25.0 (56392373)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[49]|Bytes:4
>   09:35:25.0 (56800768)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[49]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, Enrollment_Message__c, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :tmpVar1
>   09:35:25.0 (56817566)|LIMIT_USAGE|[49]|SOQL|2|100
>   09:35:25.0 (56833459)|LIMIT_USAGE|[49]|AGGS|0|300
>   09:35:25.0 (111101692)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[49]|Rows:1
>   09:35:25.0 (111123355)|LIMIT_USAGE|[49]|SOQL_ROWS|2|50000
>   09:35:25.0 (111153398)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[49]|Bytes:8
>   09:35:25.0 (111168881)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[49]|Bytes:94
>   09:35:25.0 (111290924)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[49]|Bytes:8
>   09:35:25.0 (111317663)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[49]|lstAccountToUpdate|List|true|false
>   09:35:25.0 (111365674)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[49]|lstAccountToUpdate|[{"Id":"0018A00000MJsXBQA1","Enrollment_Message__c":"You're Personal  (7 more) ...","Name":"Print"}]|0x24d88fc6
>   09:35:25.0 (111374108)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[52]
>   09:35:25.0 (111448035)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[52]|Bytes:16
>   09:35:25.0 (111458403)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[52]|accToUpdate|Account|true|false
>   09:35:25.0 (111477081)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[52]|accToUpdate|{"Id":"0018A00000MJsXBQA1","Enrollment_Message__c":"You're Personal  (7 more) ...","Name":"Print"}|0x196cae7a
>   09:35:25.0 (111483496)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[53]
>   09:35:25.0 (111489175)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[53]|Bytes:21
>   09:35:25.0 (111535072)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[53]|Bytes:26
>   09:35:25.0 (111558688)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[53]|System.debug(ANY)
>   09:35:25.0 (111586664)|USER_DEBUG|[53]|DEBUG|accToUpdate in set-->Print
>   09:35:25.0 (111595293)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[53]|System.debug(ANY)
>   09:35:25.0 (111600405)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[54]
>   09:35:25.0 (111674156)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[54]|this.Enrollment_Message__c|"You're Orange."|0x196cae7a
>   09:35:25.0 (111681123)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[55]
>   09:35:25.0 (111713357)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[55]|Bytes:8
>   09:35:25.0 (111723763)|DML_BEGIN|[55]|Op:Update|Type:Account|Rows:1
>   09:35:25.0 (111739598)|LIMIT_USAGE|[55]|DML|1|150
>   09:35:25.0 (111753149)|LIMIT_USAGE|[55]|DML_ROWS|1|10000
>   09:35:25.0 (111770256)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
>   09:35:25.0 (140901821)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q2E000000ck6o|AccountTrigger on Account trigger event BeforeUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/AccountTrigger
>   09:35:25.0 (140962558)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
>   09:35:25.0 (141004958)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
>   09:35:25.0 (141094871)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
>   09:35:25.0 (141106692)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[1]|this|AccountTrigger|true|false
>   09:35:25.0 (141139168)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1]|this|{}|0x23e0a748
>   09:35:25.0 (141163167)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
>   09:35:25.0 (141168785)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[1]|this|AccountTrigger|true|false
>   09:35:25.0 (141180388)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1]|this|{}|0x23e0a748
>   09:35:25.0 (141188512)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
>   09:35:25.0 (141209143)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[3]
>   09:35:25.0 (141218008)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[4]
>   09:35:25.0 (141224094)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[9]
>   09:35:25.0 (141226590)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[10]
>   09:35:25.0 (141868884)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[10]|Bytes:22
>   09:35:25.0 (141885317)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[10]|Bytes:64
>   09:35:25.0 (141917706)|METHOD_ENTRY|[5]|01p2E000009apDz|AccountTriggerHelper.AccountTriggerHelper()
>   09:35:25.0 (141925731)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[5]
>   09:35:25.0 (141930948)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[5]
>   09:35:25.0 (141937074)|METHOD_EXIT|[5]|AccountTriggerHelper
>   09:35:25.0 (141960833)|METHOD_ENTRY|[10]|01p2E000009apDz|AccountTriggerHelper.updateAccountStateCode(List, Map)
>   09:35:25.0 (141982698)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[87]|newAccList|List|true|false
>   09:35:25.0 (186547761)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[87]|newAccList|[{"LastModifiedDate":"2019-12-16T17:35:04.000Z","Bank_Account_Holder__c":"Print","Employer_Microsite_Link__c":"http://dev.employer. (77 more) ...","Broker_Group__c":"00G8A000001kbwuUAA","Taxpayer_Id__c":"123456789","Enrollment_Message__c":"You're Orange.","Industry__c":"Automotive Repair, S (19 more) ...","Name":"Print","Company_Owner__c":"Community Admin","Is_Authorization_Provided__c":false,"City__c":"Chicago","CreatedById":"0058A000002JfsYQAS","tender_type__c":"Account","Bank_Name__c":"HDFC","Enrollment_cutOff_date__c":"2019-12-31T00:00:00.000Z","Bank_Routing_Number__c":24242424,"State__c":"Illinois","MemberApi_Success__c":false,"Bank_Account_Type__c":"Checking","IsDeleted":false,"Quote_Accepted__c":false,"Enrollment_Status__c":"Quote Accepted","Sic":"7533","Sharing_Plans__c":false,"Plan_Effective_Date__c":"2020-01-15T00:00:00.000Z","Street_Suite__c":"Redwood","Division__c":"Services","CreatedDate":"2019-12-04T05:29:00.000Z","First_Name__c":"CEO","Id":"0018A00000MJsXBQA1","Department__c":"HR","IsPartner":false,"Last_Name__c":"Print","picklis__c":"Auto Exhaust System  (12 more) ...","Cheque_Uploaded__c":true,"Job_Title__c":"CEO","Send_Quote_From__c":"AFMC","OwnerId":"0052E00000JRYwbQAH","RecordTypeId":"0122E000000dDa2QAE","Transaction_Description__c":"Company Name Print C (28 more) ...","State_Code__c":"IL","ZIP__c":"60617","Phone_Number__c":"8087752115","Plan_End_Date__c":"2021-01-14T00:00:00.000Z","Company_Number__c":"C-00068","Send_Merchant_receipt__c":1,"Work_Email__c":"ceo.print@print.com","Bank_Account_Number__c":"24242","IsCustomerPortal":true,"Census_Group__c":"00G8A000001kbwvUAA","Client_Id__c":"3206","Employee_Microsite_Link__c":"http://dev.member.ah (75 more) ...","SystemModstamp":"2019-12-16T17:35:04.000Z","Custom_Data__c":"Caryn Health 3206","Organization__c":"AHPA","Same_as_Above__c":false,"send_customer_receipt__c":1,"LastModifiedById":"0058A000002NQhiQAG"}]|0x5d4d2968
>   09:35:25.0 (186601835)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[87]|oldAccMap|Map|true|false
>   09:35:25.0 (188652640)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[87]|oldAccMap|{"0018A00000MJsXBQA1":{"Las

Comment: would you share the logging?

Comment: What is the type of field `Enrollment_Message__c`?

Comment: This is the field type:- Rich Text Area(32768)

Comment: @SeanGorman Added Debug Logs,basically while variable assignment it is fine, but next when trigger runs,  and Trigger.newis referred, it add the characters. (you can search logs with the  word Orange)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rich Text Area fields are stored in HTML, where characters such as apostrophes are escaped. That is what you're seeing here. It's behaving as designed and cannot be changed.

From [Editing Rich Text Area Fields in Records](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_using_rich_text_area.htm&type=5)
:

> Rich text field values are returned in HTML format. Some characters are escaped when the custom field value is retrieved through the API.
>
> - Ampersand character & is returned as `&amp;`.
> - Greater than character > is returned as `&gt;`
> - Less than character < is returned as `&lt;`
> - Quote character " is returned as `&quot;`
> - Single quote character ' is returned as `&#39;`

Comment: Thanks David. I have changed the field type to normal long text area, as it was not absolutely needed there.